# How to know which application or user put the SQL Server Database in single user mode

Tags: sql-server, locking

In my case, there is SQL Server Database which is used by multiple teams. The database has suddenly gone into Single User mode. Now, how to identify the responsible user or application who did that? It could be an application as well.

If not possible now, then what to do to capture this info in the future?

Comment: Setup your database so it has the correct permissions to preclude this from happening. Prevention is better than cure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modern SQL Server versions will allow you to create a **Server Secuirty Audit**. They are a bit like the extended events, but leaner.

A basic script to set up SQL Server Security audits could look like this:

#### Create Server Security Audit

```
USE [master]
GO


/****** Object:  Audit [ServerSecurityAudit2021]    Script Date: 03.03.2021 12:39:07 ******/
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [ServerSecurityAudit2021]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'E:\MSSQL13.INSTANCENAME\MSSQL\Log\'
    ,MAXSIZE = 256 MB
    ,MAX_FILES = 10
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
)
WITH
(   QUEUE_DELAY = 1000
    ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE
)
```

#### Specify Security Audit Details

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [ServerSecurityAuditSpecs2021]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [ServerSecurityAudit2021]
ADD (DATABASE_CHANGE_GROUP),
ADD (FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP)
-- , ADD (USER_CHANGE_PASSWORD_GROUP)
-- , ADD (SERVER_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP)
-- , ADD (SERVER_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP)
-- , ADD (LOGIN_CHANGE_PASSWORD_GROUP)
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

*I commented out some of the SQL Server Audit Action Groups and Actions. A list of which can be found under [SQL Server Audit Action Groups and Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*

#### Turn On Security Audit

```
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [ServerSecurityAudit2021] WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

<sup>***Reference:** [CREATE SERVER AUDIT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-server-audit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

#### Using SSMS

You can do the same with SSMS by following the steps outlined in [Create a server audit and database audit specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs).

#### Viewing Server Audit

In the SSMS of your instance navigate to **Security | Audits | Your_Audit_Name** and right-click the audit and select **View Audit Logs**.

[image: SSMS View Audit Logs]

You can then select the **ALTER** Action ID and it will display the details of what happened.

[image: Audit Log Details]

*Details redacted to protect the innocent*

Answer (score 13):

The spid is recorded in the SQL Server error log, but not the user / application / host. And, as Grant mentioned, nothing is recorded to the built-in [`system_health` session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-system-health-session) (or the default trace, [if you still have that enabled](https://sqlblog.org/?s=removing+default+trace)).

```
EXEC sys.sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'single_user';
```

Results:

```
LogDate                   ProcessInfo   Text
-----------------------   -----------   ------------------------------------
2021-09-15 08:54:02.227   spid60        Setting database option SINGLE_USER 
                                        to ON for database 'blat'.
```

In order to catch this information in the future, you could set up an Extended Events session, e.g.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [CatchAlterDatabase] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.object_altered
(
  ACTION
  (
    sqlserver.client_app_name, sqlserver.client_hostname, 
    sqlserver.server_principal_name, sqlserver.sql_text
  ) WHERE ([object_type] = 'DATABASE')
)
ADD TARGET package0.event_file
(
  SET filename = N'CatchAlterDB.xel', 
    max_file_size=(25), max_rollover_files=(10)
)
WITH 
(
  MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB, EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
  MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS, MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB, 
  TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON
);
GO

ALTER EVENT SESSION CatchAlterDatabase ON SERVER STATE = START;
```

From right-clicking the session under Management > Extended Events > Sessions, and choosing Watch Live Data (or going to the event file and choosing View Target Data...) you can see events like this (note that the target database is actually listed under `object_name`; `database_name` is the *context* database):

> [image]

But you will also get all other alter database events. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to pull the data programmatically (and filter) using [`sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file` (docs here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-xe-file-target-read-file-transact-sql). Grant Fritchey [has a starter query here](https://www.scarydba.com/2021/04/05/extended-events-embrace-the-xml/).

There are other options, too, like [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine) / `DATABASE_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP`.

Answer (score 9):

You can't know after the fact. I checked, and system_health doesn't capture this information. However, you can set up Extended Events to capture exactly this in the future. I have examples of [auditing database changes here](https://www.scarydba.com/2020/02/24/extended-events-database-auditing/). I don't show setting it to SINGLE_USER, but the example where I change compatibility level would absolutely apply.